# Prove that the following is a constant function

Tags: analysis

Let $f : R \rightarrow R $
$\lvert f(x)-f(y)  \rvert \le (x-y)^2, \forall x,y \in R $

Any sort of help is appreciated!
I know I am not suppose to ask for the entire solution, so I will ask for strong hints.

Comment: This question is just a special case of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124263/a-condition-for-a-function-to-be-constant

Answer (score 10):

HINT: For all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$,

$$\begin{align*}
|f(x)-f(x+a)|&\le\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left|f\left(x+\frac{ka}n\right)-f\left(x+\frac{(k+1)a}n\right)\right|\\
&\le\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{a}n\right)^2\\
&=\frac{a^2}n\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: +1 for no derivative. However I'd rather say the same with more words and less formaulae: explicitly describe dividing the $[x,y]$ range of length $L=|y-x|$ into $n$ parts of equal lengths $d=\frac Ln$, then the sum of $f$ increments over all parts is directly $|f(x)-f(y)| \le nd^2=\frac {L^2}n$ which tends to $0$ for growing $n$.

Comment: @CiaPan: The whole point was *not* to say it explicitly, but rather to give, as the OP said, a strong hint -- something that would point the way reasonably clearly but still require some thought.

Comment: Well, seems I haven't read the whole question. :(

Comment: In my opinion, more words and less formulae would be a better hint than this one. This is almost an answer which can be copied directly without a thought, but the same with words would help the OP understand the point.

Comment: @JiK: It requires significant addition in the way of explanation in order to become an answer that I would accept for full credit. And in order to produce that explanation, the reader has to understand the point of the calculation; until that’s understood, it’s just a string of symbols. My goal is to give the reader enough help to arrive at that understanding on his own *without* explaining it.

Answer (score 9):

$$ \bigg|\frac{f(x)-f(y) }{x-y} -0 \bigg|\leq |x-y|$$

So if $x$ goes to $y$ then $f'(y)=0$ for all $y$

Comment: Fair enough; I was still reacting to the other answer, I guess, and didn’t think through what you were actually suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

Think about a few things:

1. The limit definition of the derivative,
2. The derivative of a constant function

And let $x$ tend to $0$

Comment: There is no reason (or need) to assume that $f$ is differentiable.